# Method is abstract or not

Tags: java, methods, mirror

Im getting the method (MethodDeclaration) for each class.

now i want to know if the method return type is abstract or not ?

how can  i do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using reflection to get a method?

Assuming that you're using Java, see [getModifiers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers%28%29) and check whether the bit is set for [Method.Abstract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#ABSTRACT)

Comment: thanks but im getting com.sun.mirror.declaration.Modifier as return type..is there anyway you can find that is abstract or not ?

Comment: Sure, just check if it is com.sun.mirror.declaration.Modifier.ABSTRACT.  Do you really want to be using that package and not just plain old reflection?

Comment: But it always return "abstract" string even though the modifer is not ??

Comment: For getModifiers that returns a collection of modifier objects.  You need to loop through those and check whether any of them == Modifier.ABSTRACT?  Why are you using this API by the way?  I think java.lang.reflect is easier to work with?

Comment: Its a generation tool using APT process which actually returns the methods of packages com.sun.mirro.etc

Comment: Is there any possible for each modifier i can check the class is abstract or not ?

Comment: @Muhammad, yeah, that's exactly it.

Comment: so should it Say for each modifier (modifier==Modifier.ABSTRACT)